# PictureBox doesn't appear

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have an `if` statement, inside that if statement is a `foreach`, for accessing each `string` from a `string[]`.

The strings are some parameters for an NPC which are read from a file. The first one represents the NPC type which are two : "battle" and "teach", the last `string[]` for a "teach" NPC is "end", and the rest of parameters represents photo names, which I want to load in a "dialog" PictureBox.

My test file looks like this:

```
teach
poza1
poza2
end
```

So I have 2 photos to load in the dialog PictureBox. The idea is that I must pause for 5 seconds that `foreach` statement, otherwise the dialog PictureBox pictures will be loaded too fast, and I won't see them.

So I tried to do that, and here is how the code looks:

```
if (date[0].Equals("teach")) //the first line of the date[] string, date represent the text from the file
{
    foreach (string parametru in date) // i think that you know what this does
    {
        if (parametru != "teach" && parametru != "end") // checking if the parameter isn't the first or the last line of the file
        {

            dialog.ImageLocation = folder + "/npc/" + score_npc + "/" + parametru + ".png"; //loading the photo
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }
    }
    //other instructions , irelevants in my opinion
}
```

In my attempt of debugging this, I realised that if I use a `MessageBox`, the function will load the both photos. Also I'm sure of the fact that the parameters will pass the if statement.

It seems so easy to fix this error, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Before you call Sleep, call `Application.DoEvents()`, although this is frowned upon and isn't typically the right thing to do. Technically you want to do a `dialog.Invoke` and in the delegate procedure set the image.

Comment: @DanielA.White yes this is in winforms

Comment: You are loading the images before the pb has time to show them. if you want to use some kind of animation a Timer would be better, but if you call PB.Refresh before the thread.Sleep it should work as well..

Comment: @RonBeyer how can i set the image in the delegate procedure

Comment: Something like `dialog.Invoke(delegate { dialog.ImageLocation = ...; });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing now just freezes the UI. Use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead. Drop a Timer from the toolbox onto your Form.

Then create some fields that the Timer can access, to store your pics and the current pic position:

```
private List<string> pics = new List<string>();
private int currentPic = 0;
```

Finally, load it up with the pics you want to display, and start the Timer to go through them:

```
pics.Clear();
pics.AddRange(date.Where(x => x != "teach" && x != "end"));
timer1.Interval = 5000;
timer1.Start();
```

Then you'll have to tell your Timer to display the next picture. Increase the counter, and reset it when necessary. Something like this should work. Modify as necessary.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dialog.ImageLocation = string.Format("{0}/npc/{1}/{2}.png", folder, score_npc, pics[currentPic]);

    currentPic++;

    if (currentPic >= pics.Count)
        currentPic = 0;

    // Alternatively, stop the Timer when you get to the end, if you want
    // if (currentPic >= pics.Count)
    //     timer1.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems it worked out with the `Application.DoEvents()` too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to issue a  PictureBox.Refresh and/or a DoEvents command for the picture box to actually get a chance to load and display the picture.

The MessageBox automatically performs a DoEvents ... which is why it is working during debugging.